# unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session

Tags: macos, bundle, xcrun

xcrun altool --notarize-app -f “xxx.pkg" --primary-bundle-id "com.xxx.xxx” --username “xxx” --password “xxx”

I specified correct username and app specific password.

The above command giving me below error, if anybody faced similar issue please let me know how to resolve the issue

Error:Unable to notarize app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the entire error message? I would expect something more detailed, like:

```
2020-08-01 12:00:00.000 altool[6000:9000] *** Error: Unable to notarize app.
2020-08-01 12:00:00.000 altool[6000:9000] *** Error: code -22016 (Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session.)
```

That second message is the explanation for the failure.

If you see the “unable to create an authentication session” message, then it is likely that the app-specific password is incorrect (or that you're using your Apple ID password instead of the app-specific password). I would suggest creating a new one. Just go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and in the **Security** section, click **Generate Password** under **App-Specific Passwords**.